# how to connect docker container with my bridge?

Tags: docker

Im a beginner with docker. I'm trying to connect my docker container with my bridge. I create my bridge(bridge0) with netplan and i add DOCKER_OPTS="-b=bridge0" in /etc/default/docker then restart docker service but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?
(I used docker version 20.10.11 on ubuntu host)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Change /etc/default/docker doesnt work. The following solution works for me:

- create /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
- create file /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/custom.conf
- modify the file :

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -b=bridge0

- systemctl deamon reload
- restart docker service